# PyCharm debug popup won't go away and blocks IDE usage, how can I fix this?

Tags: pycharm

I have a floating debug popup on my pycharm IDE screen which I cannot seem to close and it prevents me from using my pycharm, please what can I do[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9BUL.png)

I have restarted the app multiple times nothing changed

Comment: Click and drag the debug popup, drop it on the bar on the left right below where it says project.

Comment: Nothing happened Its still there